# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another procces

Tags: c#, unhandled-exception

I need to remove specific line in txt file which means i need to read and rewrite the whole file leaving out the specific line , i tried but i get unhandled-exeption (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another procces).
All i used in the processes suspicious was :

1 . this line

```
  IEnumerable<string> text = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\TreeView.txt");
```

which i used to get all lines into "string"

2. and this part of the method which supposed to delete specific line from txt

   ```
           string line = null;
           string filePath = @"c:\TreeView.txt";

           using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath, true))

           {
               using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath))
               {
                   while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                   {
                       if (String.Compare(line, obj) == 0)
                           continue;

                       sw.WriteLine(line);
                   }
               }
           }
   ```

Comment: You are opening the file for reading and then trying to write to it in that second part. Since you already read all the lines, you should be able to just make the modification and call `WriteAllLines`

Comment: You're trying to read and write the file at the same time, you've already got the file contents in "text", there is no need to read it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the second part where you are opening the file for reading and then trying to open it for writing.  You could simply do something like this:

```
var text = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\TreeView.txt");
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\TreeView.txt",
    text.Where(x => String.Compare(line, obj) != 0));
```

Comment: Do note that `ReadAllLines` an `WriteAllLines` won't scale if the files could be very large. In that case you are better off using `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`.

Comment: @NightOwl888 - That is true, but as the OP was already using `ReadAllLines` I answered in that context, but you do get an upvote on your comment.